# Best practices on remembering where the user was on php

Tags: php, session, cookies

I would like to have some advice on what could be the best practice to remember where the user was on, on a PHP script.

So we have a PHP app, that has a HTML+Js front, and on that front we're showing a paginated list of projects (via DataTables). When the user clicks on a project, the app loads a new page with the project description.

What we want to achieve is that when the user clicks on the back button of the browser, to be sent exactly where he/she was on the list (exact page and row)

We're using DataTables to list pagination and more, so positioning the user on a specific row isn't the problem.

I came to two approaches:

- **Cookies** *(client-side)*: So every time the user changes a page in the DataTable we store a cookie. Whenever the user comes back to the page, we read the cookie and position the user on that specific page/row.
- **Sessions** *(server-side)*: Every time the user lands on the project page, we store a session variable with the project ID. Whenever the user comes back to the projects list, we read the session variable, and produce the javascript needed to jump to the specific page/row where the project is.

PROS/CONS about the above?

Any other idea/recommendation?

Comment: *"What we want to achieve is that when the user clicks on the back button of the browser, to be sent exactly where he/she was on the list (exact page and row)"* ... you've got no control over that, that's just the same as having a button with JS `history.back()`

Comment: Best practices can be opinionated depending on each persons' experiences as such, your question may be closed.

Comment: @Yasin why would cookies not be costly compared to sessions? Where do you get this information?

Comment: @Yasin One of the cookies CONS is that some people navigates with cookies disabled. Thx for the comment anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always issue *unique URLs* for any place the user can navigate to, then the standard browser navigation will work just fine. If you store state in cookies or sessions (no appreciable difference here), there can only be one such state at a time and a user won't be able to open separate windows/tabs with different states. Which goes against how HTTP works.

If you link from one page to another, add parameters to the URL to express unique states, e.g.:

- http://example.com/foo/page/1
- http://example.com/foo?page=1

If you're changing the state dynamically while on the page using Javascript, perhaps add fragments to express those state changes:

- http://example.com/foo#page1

You can also use the Javascript [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) to alter the URL in other ways than just the fragment. The important part is that you can read that URL and reproduce the same state again.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you're proposing to use the URL to control and remember the situation over the navigation?

Comment: Yes, that's how browsers and HTTP are supposed to work.